# How To Uncheck Default Checkbox When Another Is Checked - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I need to have the first value "none" checked as default and then unchecked when any of the other options are checked. I have found the way to do this using the ng-model but I'm using ng-model to build an object for email. Is there a way that I can do this using an angularish style?

```
<div class="activate-mail-subsection">
         <label>Allergies</label><br>
         <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
            <input name="allergies" class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.none" tabindex="1"/> None
        </div>
         <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
             <input name="allergies" class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.codeine" tabindex="1"/> Codeine
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
             <input name="allergies" class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.sulfa" tabindex="1"/> Sulfa
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
             <input name="allergies" class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.asprin" tabindex="1"/> Asprin
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
             <input name="allergies" class="checkbox"  type="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.penicillin" tabindex="1"/> Penicillin
         </div>
            <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
                <label>Other</label>
                <input name="allergies" class="form-control health-profile-text" type="text" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.other" tabindex="1"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the object

```
  $scope.mailorder = {
    allergies: {none: true, codeine: false, sulfa: false, aspirin: false, penicillin: false, other: ''},
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep using the ng-models to handle their status. This is actually a good idea.
"none" will be set if any other value is set to true. With that in mind, you can just add a ng-click to any of your control forms in order to update the none status. 
If you want, you can also add another function to set all other controls to false upon checking the "none" box, too.

```
<div class="activate-mail-subsection">
    <label>Allergies</label>
    <br />
    <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allergies" class="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.none" tabindex="1" ng-click="setNone()" />None
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allergies" class="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.codeine" tabindex="1" ng-click="update()" />Codeine
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allergies" class="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.sulfa" tabindex="1" ng-click="update()" />Sulfa
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allergies" class="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.asprin" tabindex="1" ng-click="update()" />Asprin
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="allergies" class="checkbox" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.penicillin" tabindex="1" ng-click="update()" />Penicillin
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox mailorder-checkbox">
        <label>Other</label>
        <input type="text" name="allergies" class="form-control health-profile-text" ng-model="mailorder.allergies.other" tabindex="1" ng-change="update()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

(Notice the updateNone() and update() hooks in the HTML code).

```
angular.module("app", []).controller('Ctrl',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.mailorder = {
            allergies: {
                none: true,
                codeine: false,
                sulfa: false,
                aspirin: false,
                penicillin: false,
                other: ''
            }
        };

        $scope.setNone = function() {
            $scope.mailorder.allergies.none = true;
            // Iterate over all mailorder elements
            for (var i in $scope.mailorder.allergies) {
                if (i === 'none') {
                    continue;
                }
                $scope.mailorder.allergies[i] = null;
            }
        }

        $scope.update = function() {
            for (var i in $scope.mailorder.allergies) {
                if (i === 'none') {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($scope.mailorder.allergies[i]) {
                    $scope.mailorder.allergies.none = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
            $scope.mailorder.allergies.none = true;
        };
    }
);
```

Here's an example in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/b0JtSA7wI2XHd7KriSDp?p=preview

Comment: If it fits your need, please don't forget to mark it as a valid answer ;-)

Comment: This actually does fit my needs with a small modification. I'll be marking this as answer. But, One question. Is there a way that I can apply this to multiple sets of check boxes without having to duplicate the code and calling different functions? Ex. $scope.severity.none and so on.

Comment: not sure if you saw my comment. Is there a way to accomplish this with wildcards by chance?

Comment: Yes. Let's suppose for each criterion you'll have a "none" option. You can change the setNone() and update() functions to have a parameter, which is the criterion. I'll update the code in plunker. Hold on...

Comment: If you're really going to have several criteria, you should consider writing a directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about just making the none one a function of all the other responses?

```
 <input name="allergies" class="checkbox"  
        type="checkbox" 
        ng-checked="!mailorder.allergies.codeine && !mailorder.allergies.sulfa &!...."
```

If your list of alternatives gets longer, you could shift this to a function in your controller. In ES6 this can be done quite succinctly

```
$scope.isNone = function() {    
   return Object.values($scope.mailorder).every(r => !r)
}
```